# Listener code for Touch UI dialog for hiding/showing field inside custom-multi-field

Tags: javascript, aem

I have a component having two variations. I am trying to hide the field inside custom-multi-field (when the selection of variation is changed ) using listener in Touch-UI.I am calling the following function whenever the selection of variation is getting changed.

```
function teaserOnSelect() {
    var teaserTypeValue = $('#type :selected').val();

    if (teaserTypeValue == "variation-1") {

        console.log($("#title").parent());
        $("#title").parent().hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Nainy - Are you writing this listener code inside your custom widget file?

Comment: @Abie Yes. I am just posting the listener part.

Comment: @ozil The hiding of field is not working.